# v-show an element on multiple specified routes

Tags: vue.js

I want an element to only be rendered when NOT on two (or more) specified routes.

```
<i v-show="$route.path !== ('/account' || '/email')" class="material-icons settings-icon">
  settings
</i>
```

The above only works on the second route listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `v-show` condition is not correct.

You're applying a boolean OR to two (non-empty) strings, which will always yield the first string. That is, `('/account' || '/email')` always yields `'/account'`.

Instead, do this:

```
<i v-show="$route.path !== '/account' && $route.path != '/email'" class="material-icons settings-icon">
  settings
</i>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. My understanding of the || operator was incorrect. Cheers.